I got an error when I make cast send command
When I try to make this command cast send --rpc-url "http://94.237.62.195:44737/rpc" --private-key 0x*****b5f312b946890bc3256199b2570dded16e18a8336eeef3cfae0f8a***** 0x50A236495200fF4C70ebfd77EE01dC606c159857 "attack(uint256)" 1000 I got the next error


this is the definition of attack function:


Can you share the function definition of attack() that you're calling?
